# Override Jackson default KeyDeserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson

Im trying to override the default KeyDeserializer but it seems to work only on top level key:

The input JSON

```
{
    "upper_key":
    {
        "lower_key": "lower_value",
        "lower_key_2": "lower_value_2"
    },
    "upper_key_2": "upper_value_2"
}
```

The mapper I use

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addKeyDeserializer(Object.class, new MyKeyParser());
    mapper.registerModule(module);
    Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);
```

and the KeyDeserializer

```
public class MyKeyParser extends KeyDeserializer {

  @Override
  public String deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) {
    System.out.println(key);
    return key;
  }

}
```

The print output for the given json is:

```
upper_key
upper_key_2
```

What I expected it to be (order doesn't matter)

```
upper_key
lower_key
lower_key_2
upper_key_2
```

What I'm missing?

EDIT:
I see some answers give alternative ways to get the keys but this is not the question.
I want to understand how to use the KeyDeserializer.
My real intent is to alter the keys - for example add suffix. so I don't want to iterate over the map twice and create 2 maps.

I know I can write a Map.class Deserializer and do everything there. But the question is why the KeyDeserializer work only on top level keys and not how to manipulate maps.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't pass through a simple POJO that match json structure ? After you can manage fields as you want.

Comment: I don't know the structure of this json

Comment: You can put it in a map, jackson does that.

Comment: That's what I do, update the example with: 
`Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class)`

Comment: do you have to use the `KeyDeserializer` ?

Comment: yes, I have to use KeyDeserializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that Jackson doesn't use the `KeyDeserializer` for nested objects is explained by [Le0pold's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75771952/12763954).
However, there is a trick to make it work as expected (tested with Jackson 2.12.7): call
[`addAbstractTypeMapping()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleModule.html#addAbstractTypeMapping-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-) like this:

```java
import java.util.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addKeyDeserializer(Object.class, new MyKeyParser());
        module.addAbstractTypeMapping(Map.class, LinkedHashMap.class); // this line does the trick
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        String jsonString = "{\"upper_key\": {\"lower_key\": \"lower_value\", \"lower_key_2\": \"lower_value_2\"}, \"upper_key_2\": \"upper_value_2\"}";
        Map map = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);
    }

    public static class MyKeyParser extends KeyDeserializer
    {
        @Override
        public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
        {
            System.out.println(key);
            return key;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
upper_key
lower_key
lower_key_2
upper_key_2
```

Comment: it works! can you explain why the AbstractTypeMapping helps?

Comment: @Boaz I think the reason is [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/07ac7a71c9bc406827ba4e3e2708dbda6ec451f7/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/UntypedObjectDeserializer.java#L247): when you set an explicit Map type, `UntypedObjectDeserializer` doesn't call `mapObject()` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at KeyDeserializer javadoc:

> KeyDeserializer: class that defines API used for deserializing JSON content field names into Java Map **keys**.

Note word keys here. KeyDeserializer is used **only** for map keys deserialization. In your case your target type is `Map<String, Object>`. Any other types aren't affected by KeyDeserializer. That is the reason why your code behaves like that. Jackson basically does next steps:

1. It sees target type as *Map<String, Object>*. It means that for deserializaiton *MapDeserializer* class should be used.
2. *MapDeserializer* uses for keys deserialization class that you provided.
3. For values deserialization *UntypedObjectDeserializer* is used, because value type is object.

With your initial JSON it is impossible to apply key deserializer so lower keys will be affected by key deserializer: you need to have Map type instead of object. If you will use next JSON (I removed second upper key from original JSON because I want object to strictly match *Map<String, Map<String, String>>*):

```json
{
    "upper_key":
    {
        "lower_key": "lower_value",
        "lower_key_2": "lower_value_2"
    }
}
```

and next code (Note that key deserializer registered for Object type, and map typed as "Object to Map", i.e. "Object to *Map<Object, Object>*"):

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addKeyDeserializer(Object.class, new MyKeyParser());

mapper.registerModule(module);

MapType mapType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, Object.class, Map.class);

Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = mapper.readValue(jsonString, mapType);
```

output will be as you want:

```
upper_key
lower_key
lower_key_2
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but as you mentioned your answer does not apply to my original json. The type have to be Map<String, Object>  and not  Map<String, Map>.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for overriding a Deserializer. For dynamic JSONs you could simply use a JsonNode and then parse the structure however you want afterwards:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readValue("""
            {
                "upper_key":
                {
                    "lower_key": "lower_value",
                    "lower_key_2": "lower_value_2"
                },
                "upper_key_2": "upper_value_2"
            }""", JsonNode.class);

    extractKeys(jsonNode);
}

public static void extractKeys(JsonNode jsonNode) {

    jsonNode.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(name -> {
        System.out.println(name);
        JsonNode subnode = jsonNode.get(name);

        if (subnode.isObject()) {
            extractKeys(subnode);
        }
    });
}
```

prints:

```
upper_key
lower_key
lower_key_2
upper_key_2
```

Comment: I don't want to print the json. I just want the keys

Comment: extracting the keys form this should be more than easy.

Comment: @Boaz added an example how to get the keys.

Comment: added explanation in the question. Im not looking for way to manipulate maps in Java. The question is why KeyDeserializer doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

KeyDeserializer call deserialize Key just for upper key. but you can get all keys by creating your own implementation for example

```
private static void getAllKeysUsingJsonNodeFieldNames(JsonNode value, List<String> keys) {
        if (value.isObject()) {
            Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = value.fields();
            fields.forEachRemaining(field -> {
                keys.add(field.getKey());
                getAllKeysUsingJsonNodeFieldNames((JsonNode) field.getValue(), keys);
            });
        } else if (value.isArray()) {
            ArrayNode arrayField = (ArrayNode) value;
            arrayField.forEach(node -> {
                getAllKeysUsingJsonNodeFieldNames(node, keys);
        });
    }
}
```

and call it from your main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readValue(jsonString, JsonNode.class);
        getAllKeysUsingJsonNodeFieldNames(jsonNode, keys);
        System.out.println(keys);
}
```

Comment: "KeyDeserializer call deserialize Key just for upper key" -> where did you see this written?